# How to position element in a fixed position inside DIV

Tags: php, css, html-table

What do I need to do in order to have these two "Read Now" buttons in same position in each div box, no matter how long the description above them is?

http://jsfiddle.net/ThaXt/

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="51" valign="middle" style="background: url(../../images/playonline3.jpg)" ><h1>HEADING</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="150" align="left" valign="top" class="body-text" style="padding:10px">

        <div class="box">
            <p class="box-title"><a href="http://LINK/">Title1</a></p>
            <p class="box-desc">This article explains bluffing in general and shows examples of good bluffing spots.</p>
            <a href="http://LINK" id="button4" class="buttonText">Read Now</a>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td height="150" align="left" valign="top" class="body-text" style="padding:10px">

        <div class="box">
            <p class="box-title"><a href="http://LINK">Double Barreling</a></p>
            <p class="box-desc">What is a double barrel and when do we use this strategy?</p>
            <a href="http://LINK" id="button4" class="buttonText">Read Now</a>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: It's not 2013 to use `<table/>` for the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ThaXt/1/

Using `position: absolute;` you can tell the buttons to stay at a very specific point, and they will never move from there.

I added `position: relative;` to the class `.box`

I then added `position: absolute;` `bottom: 10px;` and `left: 0;` to your ID `#button4`

```
.box {
    width: 250px;
    height: 137px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #BEBEBE;
    background-color: #F6F6F6;
    color: #990000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height: 20px;
}

#button4 {
    background: #5c5c5c;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
/* ... your other styles below ... */
}
```

Comment: About to answer Micheal :) u posted it

Comment: I would also give the .box a "padding-bottom" to always have enough space for the button.

Comment: @user1254824 Yes, in fact it would be advisable to give .box a padding around the entire thing.  As it stands this button has margin space to create that space.  One should always use padding over margin where ever possible.  To that extent he should also not be using table for layout and a few other things could be improved for readability.  But his problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use `style="position: absolute; left: {number}; top: {number};"`. Using `position: absolute;` you can put the button where you want. Here I wrote your code with some edits. Just Copy and Paste it:

```
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="51" valign="middle" style="background: url(../../images/playonline3.jpg)" ><h1>HEADING</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="150" align="left" valign="top" class="body-text" style="padding:10px">

        <div class="box">
            <p class="box-title"><a href="http://LINK/">Title1</a></p>
            <p class="box-desc">This article explains bluffing in general and shows examples of good bluffing spots.</p>
            <a href="http://LINK" id="button4"  style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 190px;"  class="buttonText">Read Now</a>
        </div>

    </td>

    <td height="150" align="left" valign="top" class="body-text" style="padding:10px">

        <div class="box">
            <p class="box-title"><a href="http://LINK">Double Barreling</a></p>
            <p class="box-desc">What is a double barrel and when do we use this strategy?</p>
            <a href="http://LINK" id="button4" style="position: absolute; left: 290px; top: 190px;" class="buttonText">Read Now</a>
        </div>

    </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: It is NEVER advisable to use inline styling, especially when CSS is available via JSFiddle.